# animate slide show php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Can someone help me with this script I want to animate sliding Image Gallery with jQuery and Javascript and PHP but it doesn't execute

```
<div class="gallwrapper" >
    <div class="gallmask">
        <ul class="gallul">
        <?php if( is_array($images )): ?>
            <?php foreach($images as $key => $value ): ?>
                <?php if($value !="." && $value !=".."):?>
                    <li class="gallli">
                        <img class="gallimg" src ="gallary/<?php echo $value ?>" />
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btnleft" >
    <div class="leftbtn-inner" style =" background-image:url('right.png');background-size: 35px 80px;background-repeat:no-repeat;" >
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btnright" >
    <div class="rightbtn-inner"  style =" background-image:url('left.png');background-size: 35px 80px;background-repeat:no-repeat;"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use open source Slider like http://www.jssor.com/

Comment: Could you also include javascript code?